# How to add external libraries to qt4 application c++

Tags: c++, qt4, qmake

what is the best way to add additional compiled libraries to my qt project ?
For example boost or poco libs ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're using the GCC compiler add something like this to the .pro file:

For Boost:

```
INCLUDEPATH += d:/Biblioteki/C++/boost/boost_1_44_0a
LIBPATH     += d:/Biblioteki/C++/boost/boost_1_44_0a/stage/lib
LIBS        += -lboost_system-mgw44-mt-d-1_44
LIBS        += -lboost_filesystem-mgw44-mt-d-1_44
LIBS        += -lboost_date_time-mgw44-mt-d-1_44
```

---

For Poco:

```
INCLUDEPATH += d:/Biblioteki/C++/Poco/poco-1.3.6p2-mingw-qt2/include
LIBPATH     += d:/Biblioteki/C++/Poco/poco-1.3.6p2-mingw-qt2/lib
LIBS        += -lPocoFoundationd
LIBS        += -lPocoNetd
LIBS        += -lPocoUtild
LIBS        += -lPocoXML
```

---

`INCLUDEPATH` - is the location of directory with header files
`LIBPATH` - is the location of directory with *.a files 
`LIBS` - contains list of libraries you want to use in your application

Comment: Message from the future, in 2014: "Variable LIBPATH is deprecated; use QMAKE_LIBDIR instead."

Comment: How to do this in a cross-system way, so other developers don't have to have the libs installed in some hardcoded location like `d:/...`?

Comment: @Seba how to add libz.tbd? i tried LIBS += -lz looks not working