# Installing/using SDL for Qt

Tags: qt, dll, sdl

I'm trying to install the [SDL library](http://www.libsdl.org/) for Qt 5.1 on Windows 7, but I'm stuck.  I'm a total newbie with using external libraries so please bear with me, I figured this sort of thing would be pretty basic to set up.

I downloaded the *SDL-devel-1.2.15-mingw32.tar.gz (Mingw32)* file, extracted it, and in my project's PRO file I added:

> INCLUDEPATH += "C:\SDL\SDL-1.2.15\include\SDL"
>
> LIBS += "C:\SDL\SDL-1.2.15\bin\SDL.dll"

Now when I try to compile this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "SDL.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get this:

> crt0_c.c:-1: error: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
>
> collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Compiling with SDL and g++ cannot find -lSDLmain etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380254/compiling-with-sdl-and-g-cannot-find-lsdlmain-etc?rq=1)

[Undefined reference to WinMain@16 when using SDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115153/undefined-reference-to-winmain16-when-using-sdl)

I am sure one of those is also applicable to your question.

Comment: What's the syntax for adding the linker path and those compiler flags? (I'd ask on those threads but it says I need 50 rep.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314735/how-to-add-external-libraries-to-qt4-application-c same for Qt5

Comment: Hey hey, it done worked.  Thank you for dealing with my noobishness.

Comment: We all were noobs once. And on the majority off topics we still are and will ever be. :-)

Answer (score 0):

SDL should be prevented from overloading main method. To do so, add the following piece of code wherever you include SDL headers.

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_thread.h>

#ifdef __MINGW32__
#undef main /* Prevents SDL from overriding main() */
#endif
```

To make it working in your case, your project.pro file should be like this:

> LIBS += -LC:\SDL-devel-1.2.15-mingw32\SDL-1.2.15\lib -llibSDL
>   INCLUDEPATH +=C:\SDL-devel-1.2.15-mingw32\SDL-1.2.15\include

As it is eveident from my code, I am using sdl version 1.2.15, 32-bit for mingw compiler on Windows 8.

Reference:

To find a good tutorial about the SDL ffmpeg integration, you can refer to [dranger](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial02.html).